# How do I deal with browsers complaining that my MediaWiki website has unsecure resources?

Tags: encryption, tls

I recently bought a subscription to a NameCheap shared hosting plan, and I plan to primarily run MediaWiki on it. I've managed to setup everything fine except for the SSL encryption. When I visit my website (https://www.jcwiki.website/wiki/Main_Page), my Chrome browser tells me that my website is verified by "COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA", but it also tells me that there are "other resources that are insecure". So basically my question is, "What do I do to make Google Chrome and other web browsers say that my website is 100% secure?"

I know that the certificate is verified, but essentially, I am not sure what else to do in this situation. Perhaps someone could explain what Chrome means by "other insecure resources"?

---

**Edit:** I checked my LocalSettings.php and saw the $wgServer variable was set to https://www.jcwiki.website so I don't think it was a problem there. Good guess though!

Comment: SSL Labs gives your site an 'A' rating. Good enough for me.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jcwiki.website&hideResults=on

Comment: 2 Security Warnings on FF: `Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://julian.referata.com/w/images/background-normal.png" on a secure page`, `Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://juliancubillos.com/favicon.ico" on a secure page`

Comment: @nhahtdh I changed my CSS and JS to point to the new webhost and now everything is secure. That makes sense that Chrome would say that it was insecure before. Thanks! :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Whats wrong?

The waring you are getting is about "Mixed-Mode" which is basically when some parts of a site are sent over HTTPS and others are sent over HTTP.

Some people down play this as unimportant because "The important data is encrypted" and while in a sense they are correct it can still be a security risk. Browser generally flag it for two reason:

1. It leads to a false sense of security, you see HTTPS and think 'everything is encrypted' but it's not *all* encrypted and the browser doesn't know what's important and whats not.
2. It can still allow people with Man-in-the-Middle access to inject content and change the site.

### How to fix it?

I personally find FireFox very helpful here<sup>1</sup> if you load the page in FireFox and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the Developers Tools. Then go to the console it will show you any errors when loading the page.

[image: Mixed-Mode]

In this case there are two files `/w/images/background-normal.png` and `/favicon.ico` that are getting loaded over http. You can either change these by editing your MediaWiki to load them over HTTPS all the time by putting the full url including the `https://` or make them relative links (e.g. just link to `/w/images/background-normal.png`) and it will load over whatever protocol the rest of the site is using.

---

1. As you say you're using Chrome I assume it can do the same thing, but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a small audit if your site, here are my findings.

- [ssllabs test report grade A](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.jcwiki.website&hideResults=on) which is good
- a `curl -vvv https://www.jcwiki.website/wiki/Main_Page | grep "http:"` yielded no results, also good.
- Opening the site in Google Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.152) incognito window yields a mixed content warning.
  I checked the development tools and the reason is that a request to  '[https://www.jcwiki.website/w/load.php](https://www.jcwiki.website/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%7Cmediawiki.ui.button%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector&*)' results in a redirect to the http variant. HTTPS pages should load EVERYTHING over HTTPS. (ergo chrome complains).

you can see the error in action through the following curl command

`curl 'https://www.jcwiki.website/w/load.php?debug=false&lang=en&modules=mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint%2Cshared%7Cmediawiki.skinning.interface%7Cmediawiki.ui.button%7Cskins.vector.styles&only=styles&skin=vector&*' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1' -H 'Referer: http://www.jcwiki.website/wiki/Main_Page' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed -vvv`

---

After some more research I suspect the `$wgServer` variable in `LocalSettings.php` is not setup right. [source](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.phphttp://)

---

I see you are using apache to host your site, you can use this vhost snippet to redirect http to https in apache :
`<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>`

[Source](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) and [Source 2](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) for using rewrite

Answer (score 2):

(Moved from comment to answer)

On Firefox, I found 2 Security Warnings in the Console:

```
Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://julian.referata.com/w/images/background-normal.png" on a secure page
Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://juliancubillos.com/favicon.ico" on a secure page
```

They are most likely the reason why a warning sign is displayed, since the page is loading some content from unsecured HTTP protocol.